# Vue - @click to send id value between two API using Axios

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, api, vue.js, axios

I'm stuck at this problem and can't find solution on Vue.JS docs.
This is what I'm getting:
I have a list with cars models from a API, that have "name" and "id", so I after I click on "Show Data" I should send id for a second API call and show all car brands for that model.
I've created a alert to see if @click works fine and collect the ID that I need.
On my alert, I'm getting only the model name or id, and I can't send this to my second api url.
This is my data where I get array items:

```
  const API_URL = "https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas";
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      brands: [],
      models: [],
      loading: true,
      errored: false,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getModels();
    this.getBrands();
  },
```

methods with API calls:

```
methods: {
async getBrands() {
  await axios
    .get(API_URL)
    .then((response) => {
      this.brands = response.data;
      console.log(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      this.errored = true;
    })
    .finally(() => (this.loading = false));
},
getBrand() {
  axios
    .get(
      "https://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/"+this.brandSelected+"/modelos"
    )
    .then((response) => {
      this.models = response.data.modelos;
      console.log(response.data.modelos);
    });
},
```

and my @click with modelSelected:

```
brandSelected (brand){
  this.brands = brand.codigo;
  alert(model.codigo);
}
  },
});
```

I'm not getting my second api call working with this.brandSelected with id from first api.
This is my HTML where I have a call for first api and @click button:

```
 <tbody v-for="(brand, index) in brands" :key="index">
              <tr>
                <td>{{brand.nome}} com código {{brand.codigo}}</td>
                <td>
                  <a
                    @click="brandSelected(brand)"
                    data-toggle="modal"
                    data-target="#modelsModal"
                    >Ver modelos</a
                  >
                </td>
```

---

I can see the model name inside my alert, using my code... But can't send to second api using this.brandSelected!
Where I'm doing this wrong? Can't find it!

---

Here you can check data from api:
brand:

```
Array [5]
0: Object
nome: "Acura"
codigo: "1"
1: Object
nome: "Agrale"
codigo: "2"
2: Object
nome: "Alfa Romeo"
codigo: "3"
3: Object
nome: "AM Gen"
codigo: "4"
4: Object
nome: "Asia Motors"
codigo: "5"
```

models with brand code:

```
Object
anos: Array [5] // not used
modelos: Array [5]
0: Object
nome: "AMAROK CD2.0 16V/S CD2.0 16V TDI 4x2 Die"
codigo: 5585
1: Object
nome: "AMAROK CD2.0 16V/S CD2.0 16V TDI 4x4 Die"
codigo: 5586
2: Object
nome: "AMAROK Comfor. CD 2.0 TDI 4x4 Dies. Aut."
codigo: 8531
3: Object
nome: "AMAROK CS2.0 16V/S2.0 16V TDI 4x2 Diesel"
codigo: 5748
4: Object
nome: "AMAROK CS2.0 16V/S2.0 16V TDI 4x4 Diesel"
codigo: 5749
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be treating `this.brandSelected` like a string in your URL but it only appears to be defined as a method.

It seems you want to do two things when you click a *brand*...

1. Store the selected brand somewhere, and
2. Load the brand's models

Try something like this and make sure to check your browser console for the log messages and any errors...

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: () => ({
    brands: [],
    models: [],
    selectedBrand: null, // store the selected brand in this property
    loading: true,
    errored: false
  }),
  methods: {
    async getBrands () {
      this.loading = true
      this.errored = false
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(API_URL)
        console.log("getBrands:", data)
        this.brands = data
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
        this.errored = true
      }
      this.loading = false
    },
    async getModels (brandCode) {
      console.log("Loading brand models for brand code:", brandCode)
      this.models = []
      const { data } = await axios.get(`${API_URL}/${encodeURIComponent(brandCode)}/modelos`)
      this.models = data.modelos
    },
    brandSelected (brand) {
      console.log("brand selected:", JSON.stringify(brand))
      // store the selected brand (in case you need it)
      this.selectedBrand = brand

      // load the brand's models
      this.getModels(brand.codigo)
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: hello, Phil!
Your code is working, but I still have doubts about this.
I keep getting two errors on console:
```GEThttps://parallelum.com.br/fipe/api/v1/carros/marcas/undefined/modelos```   
and   
```Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 404```   
I still can return all models...

Comment: That means your `brand` objects don't have a `codigo` property. Please edit your question to show what the data looks like

Comment: I think you may not have copied my answer correctly then. There is no way you should be getting `undefined` in the URL as long as you're still using `@click="brandSelected(brand)"`

Comment: If I only copy and paste, nothing is rendered... I don't know why.
As long I only copy your methods and create a data selectedBrand, things works fine...
I'm still using ```@click="brandSelected(brand)"```

Comment: @LucasMarra time to do some debugging then. I'll add some example console logging to my answer to get you started

Comment: I'll take a sleep since here is 01:30am.   I'll rewrite all my code using yours by base.